# how to search for each line of texarea data in mysql and display the result in html table?

Tags: php, mysql

hi i am taking textarea data which are imageurl links one below each other and trying to search for those image urls in mysql db and if the imageurl found in db then display the full row information in html table.

I tried the following code but i get empty html table! i dont get any mysql error either! i am not sure if i am separating  each line of textarea data correctly or not!could any one tell me what i am doing wrong?

form:

```
<form method="post" action="./doit.php">
 <textarea id="links" name="links" rows="20" cols="100">
 example text
 </textarea>
<br>
<input type="submit" name="mysubmit" value="find" />
 </form>

</html>
```

phpcode:

```
$textarea_value = $_POST['links'];
$lines = explode("\n", $textarea_value);



$server   = "localhost"; // MySQL hostname
$username = "xxxxx"; // MySQL username
$password = "xxxxx"; // MySQL password
$dbname   = "xxxxx"; // MySQL db name

$db = mysql_connect($server, $username, $password) or die(mysql_error());
      mysql_select_db($dbname) or die(mysql_error());

echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>user name</th>
<th>page URL</th>
</tr>";


foreach ($lines as $line) {

$result = mysql_query("SELECT ID,username,imageUrl,imagePageURL FROM mydb WHERE imageUrl = '$line'");
             if (!$result) {
             die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
            }

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['username'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['imagePageURL'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
}

};

echo "</table>";

?>
```

Comment: try and insert a `print_r( $lines );` to check the result of your explode function. This could probably hint you towards the problem.

Comment: thanks. i tried that by using print_r inside for each .The result of explode function is correct i get all lines of texarea in array but why my sql statement cant find the data and display them ?

Comment: hum... echo your Querystring once to check it and compare to your table? Seems like the WHERE condition is incorrect or something.

Comment: thanks for reply .could you tell me how i can echo querysting ? i tried using echo $result and i got this error :Catchable fatal error: Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to string in

Comment: Simply split the String and your query like this:
`$query = "SELECT ID,username,imageUrl,imagePageURL FROM mydb WHERE imageUrl = '$line'";
$result = mysql_query( $query );
echo $query;`

Comment: i tried this and i get this erro:SELECT ID,username,imageUrl,imagePageURL FROM mydb WHERE imageUrl = 'http://somesite.images.com/43545345454_8.jpg 'Invalid query: . How to use double quotes around image url in select statement  ?

Comment: you could escape them while assigning, like this: `$query = "SELECT ... \"YOUR LINK HERE\"; "` Try to add correct quotes for each column and the tablename too. Its single quotes for columns and those accent-quote things for the tablename